# Dapper is crashing when load is increased

Tags: dapper, stress-testing

I am using dapper in a payment processing application built on .net 5.0. In unit testing, everything was working fine, but when I used JMeter to put the load of 100 users, after processing few transactions, the dapper started crashing with the below error:

> Exception[System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be open
> for this operation    at
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ValidateStatePriorToExecution()
> at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn,
> CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 2822    at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 572    at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1
> commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 443

The code for SP execution is below:

```
public static int ExecuteSP(string spName, object parameters)
{
    IDbConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetConnection(_ConnectionString);

    int result = connection.Execute(spName, parameters, null, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    ConnectionManager.CloseConnection();
    return result;
}

public static IDbConnection GetConnection(string connectionString)
{
     DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;

     if (_oracleConnection == null)
     {
         _oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString(connectionString));
     }

     if (_oracleConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
     {
         _oracleConnection.Open();
     }
     return _oracleConnection;
}
```

Is there anything I am missing in configuration or use of Dapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is using a `static` - and therefore shared - connection (even though it isn't shown, we can assume that `_oracleConnection` is `static` because it is accessed from the `static` method `GetConnection`).

Connections **are not thread-safe**, and by making it `static`, all your code is sharing a single connection. This tends to scale to exactly one user, i.e. one concurrent request - above that: failure is pretty much guaranteed.

Connections should be scoped for a logical piece of code - which could be anywhere between "a single method" to "an entire request", but they must *only* be accessed by one thread at a time. You should also ensure that connections are correctly disposed as they leave that scope, to prevent leaking connections.

(BTW: the problem isn't really related to Dapper; the exact same problems would occur for any similar usage - whether ADO.NET, Dapper, EF, or anything else)

Comment: I want to separate the database manager class which will contain all query execution methods. These methods will be called from different classes where data is required. But the problem I am facing is the data returned by connection.Query or connection.QueryMultiple functions are only accessible till the connection is open. However I want to do a generalized implementation of these methods. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ShaziaTabassum the only *problem* here is the static connection; everything else is fine; a simple fix would be to just *throw away the connection field completely*, and just new one up each time from the connection string (you can store *that* in a static field - that's fine) - i.e. `using var conn = new SqlConnection(s_ConnectionString);` (or similar with a "using block" if you're using earlier C# versions) - but have that *per call to the data access layer*, such that the connection is local; the "connection pool" will make it still fast, etc

Comment: See the below method, if i close the connection here, i ll lost the out value received in 'parameters' variable:

`public static void GetOutputParameters(string spName, object parameters)
{
      IDbConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);

     connection.Query(spName, param: parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

     //connection.Close();
}`

Comment: @Shazia it isn't clear to me what you mean there - also, that should probably be `Execute`, not `Query`, since you aren't using the result. Closing the connection makes very little difference there, unless you're doing something *very* unusual

Comment: Actually I am using its result in the caller method. And want this _GetOutputParameter_ method as generic so that it can be called from multiple classes. But if I close the connection here, i wont be able to use the result in caller method. And if I do not close the connection then there would be connection leakage

Comment: @Shazia "But if I close the connection here, i wont be able to use the result in caller method." Why? I have absolutely no clue what you're trying to describe here? Are you returning a cursor from the sp or something?

Comment: Yes i wanted to return the db cursor from generic DBManager class to the caller class. I have found the solution and implemented it as:
`public static (GridReader, IDbConnection) ExecuteQueryWithDBCursors(string spName, object parameters)
{
     IDbConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_connectionString);
     connection.Open();
     GridReader multi = connection.QueryMultiple(spName, param: parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
     return (multi, connection);
}`
I have used the cursor value in caller method, and then closed the connection in caller method.